# Firebug not showing http error status code 401

Tags: firebug

I usually check for status codes in the Net tab in Firebug.

But it doesn't seem to work when it's a 401, it just says "3 requests", but they are not listed, I can't see the status codes, and I can't open them. Is there a reason for this?

I know I could use Live Http Headers, but it isn't as convenient.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have selected a filter? (they are on the right of the "Persistent" button). 
To see all the requests, "All" should be selected.

Comment: What version of Firebug (last stable=1.12.2) + Firefox (last stable=24.0) do you use?
And did you try this : https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Install_Firebug_into_a_clean_profile

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is probably way too late, but it looks like this might be a feature included in Firebug by design.

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4758

I must confess I've only skim-read the above issue, but it gives me the impression that information about 401s has deliberately suppressed in order to prevent the NTLM authentication protocol filling up the Firebug error console.

Comment: I can find these bugs also reporting the same or similar issue: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7162 http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5154